# How can I align the text inside "\subsection" with "\subsection"?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, numbering

How I can align the text inside `\subsection` with `\subsection`.

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the `enumerate` einvironment?

Comment: if you want someone to correct your code, you need to show your code, looking at the image It looks like an enumerate list, how are you using `\subsection` ?

Comment: For most document classes, \section and \subsection use \@hangfrom, which means the indentation depends on the width of \thesection or \thesubsection.  But this appears to be some other document class.

Comment: What you show looks nothing like a normal `\subsection`. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you have done.